# Can't open data from external hard drive, Qgis 3.10

Tags: qgis

In the Browser panel and in the Data source manager of Qgis 3.10, I can only open shapefiles and rasters saved in /home and some files in /. There is no path to my external hard drive : no /run/media. I can't open the data saved in my external hard drive.

[Browser panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUVgm.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch in /media or /mnt not in /run .

Comment: /media and /mnt are empty. The full path to my external drive is : /run/media/my_name/name_of_my_external_drive

Comment: What's your OS ?

Comment: It is Mageia 7.